# How to use django functionality "datastructures.SortedDict" in flask?

Tags: python

```
from django.utils import datastructures
meters_info = datastructures.SortedDict([
            ("instance", {
                'label': '',
                'description': _("Existence of instance"),
            }),
            ("instance:<type>", {
                'label': '',
                'description': _("Existence of instance <type> "
                                 "(openstack types)"),
            }),
            ("memory", {
                'label': '',
                'description': _("Volume of RAM"),
            }),])
```

I am converting django app to flask. They are using datastructures.SortedDict. How get the same functionality in flask

Comment: Try [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict); `datastructures.SortedDict` is no longer available in Django 1.8.

Answer (score 2):

Python has included its own [`OrderedDict` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) in the collections module since version 2.7.

Comment: on top of the official docs, read [this tutorial](http://pymotw.com/2/collections/ordereddict.html). `OrderedDict` is pure python, so you can use it in Flask.